# Unable to reach Plex using SSH reverse tunneling

Tags: ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel, plex

I've got Plex installed on a Windows computer at home. My internet connection goes over CG-NAT, so in order to access home I use an SSH reverse tunnel against a dedicated Linux server that I have on OVH.

This is the tunnel line that is running in my Windows machine at home:

```
ssh -i C:\Users\plex/.ssh/id_ed25519 -N -R *:1135:localhost:1135 -R *:32400:localhost:32400 -R *:8082:localhost:8082 nickel@server34553.ovh.com
```

As you can see, I'm tunneling other ports to access other services (like a webserver) that are working fine.

But when I try to reach Plex (`http://server34553.ovh.com:32400`), I get an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.
If I try to reach Plex at home using another computer (LAN connected), it also doesn't work with the external domain, but it works pointing to the local address (http://192.168.10.123:32400)

1. Remote access is enabled in Plex.
2. In Plex -> Network -> Custom access URLs , `http://server34553.ovh.com:32400` is also present with HTTP/S and also with the server IP.

I can only access my Plex's home server by using `plex.tv` with their "relay service", which is what I'm trying to do on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm tunneling other ports to access other services (like a webserver) that are working fine.

If you simply need access to the web interface for Plex, (i.e. what you would get with ex. `http://192.168.10.123:32400`), you might want to try using a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

You don't mention much about the web server you have working, but assuming it is on the same network (or even on the same PC) as the Plex server, that may do the job.

As a small example, I use Apache with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), `mod_proxy_html` and  `mod_proxy_http` enabled in `httpd.conf` and the following snippet in a [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
#ServerAlias www.example.com, *.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/the/example.com/folder/"

# Reverse proxies cannot occur in a <Directory> section.

ProxyPass /plex http://10.0.0.100:32400
ProxyPassReverse /plex http://10.0.0.100:32400

ProxyPass /web http://10.0.0.100:32400/web
ProxyPassReverse /web http://10.0.0.100:32400/web

</VirtualHost>
```

In the example above, `http://example.com/plex/` is just a "convenience" URL to log in. `http://example.com/web/` is what all the actual server URLs are built around (i.e. after logging in).

**Notes**

- In my experience, Remote Access needs to be enabled in Plex for proxying to work correctly (but I have a blank Custom Access URL).
- I am not behind CG-NAT. I am logged into Plex (required for Remote Access, above), however, no ports are open in my router and ex. `example.com:32400` returns nothing.
- Media played from the web UI should work properly, including videos, music and plugins.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, the server (apache) is running in the same machine where Plex is. Will reverse proxy work when playing medias from the ui too?
I will immediately test it when i'm at home!

Comment: Yes, IT WORKED, YOU'RE GOD!

Comment: Lol well I'm glad it worked for you. Thank you. =)